# How do I send http-only cookies using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

According this [this post](https://www.quora.com/What-type-of-cookies-are-automatically-extracted-by-HTTP-Cookie-Manager-component-of-Jmeter), Jmeter's cookie manager does not automatically extract and send HTTP-only cookies.

Is it possible to force JMeter to send HTTP only cookies?

Comment: You want to **send** cookie? the post is about **extract** and also it state it's working -  *apart fromHttpOnly which can still be worked* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter should normally handle [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookies.

Evidence:

- Request 1 - you can see that `NID` cookies is `HttpOnly`

  [image]
- Request 2 - you can see that JMeter sends `NID` cookie which is `HttpOnly`

  [image]

It might be the case the cookie, you're receiving does not correspond to the [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) therefore JMeter rejects it, if this is the case you can do the following:

1. Raise the issue in order to fix the cookie on the application under test side
2. Change `Cookie Policy` value in the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to something less restrictive, i.e. `netscape`

   [image]
3. Add `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` line to [*user.properties*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) file - it disables JMeter cookies integrity check.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)